# Access denied to folder in one class but not another

Tags: c#, .net, access-denied

I get an exception when trying the rename a folder with this code:

```
Directory.Move(@"D:\MyOldFolderName", @"D:\MyNewFolderName");
```

The exception:

```
System.IO.IOException was unhandled
  Message="Access to the path 'D:\\MyOldFolderName' is denied."
  Source="mscorlib"
  StackTrace:
     at System.IO.Directory.Move(String sourceDirName, String destDirName)
     ...
```

The thing is, the EXACT same codeline works in another class of my application. The application only consist of one single DLL.

**What is happening here? Any ideas?**

More info:

- The application is a WPF application,
  using the MVVM design pattern.
- The class where the folder rename
  DOES work is a ViewModel.
- The class where the folder rename
  does NOT work is a helper class (the
  method does some database related
  stuff before trying to rename the
  folder).

Comment: Are both running on the same thread?

Answer (score 4):

This is probably not due to rights but to the fact that somewhere in the code you're opening files/streams from those folders... put a breakpoint before you try to move the folder and examine that folder with some tool like [Who Lock Me](http://www.dr-hoiby.com/WhoLockMe/) or similar to see are there any differences when the first class does it, and the second one... I would expect that just before you try to move the folder with the 'failing' class the folder you're moving is locked (in use)...